# Web service denying a passed string, on Android with KSoap2

Tags: java, android, soap, ksoap2

I'm creating an Android application that communicates with a SOAP web service, and I'm using KSoap2 to do it. KSoap 2 has been functional (though a little unreliable at times) for the calls I make, except for one. The particular service call I am making is to register an account, which takes some user information, along with a "registration code". This code is used to ensure that a user is a member of a school before letting them register an account with the app. The problem is this: suppose that the registration code that the web service expects is "student123". No matter what string I pass into the web service call, I always get a response saying that the code is invalid.

I can be positive that the web service isn't the problem, as I can manually invoke the method and it works just fine, and I can even call the same SOAP method from an iPhone application that I developed for the same purpose as this Android one.

So my question is this: could KSoap2 be changing the string at all when it calls the web service? I've tried changing the registration code to just a single character like "a", but it still comes back with an invalid code response. Here is some of my code. This is inside a class that extends AsyncTask:

```
protected Object doInBackground(UserProfile...profiles) 
    {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, REGISTER);

        Vector<PropertyInfo> properties = makeProperties(ServiceCall.REGISTER, profiles[0]);

        for(int i = 0; i < properties.size(); ++i)
        {
            request.addProperty(properties.get(i));
        }

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        try
        {
            HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            transport.debug = true;

            transport.call(SOAP_NAMESPACE + REGISTER, envelope);
            Log.d("REGREQUEST", transport.requestDump);
            Log.d("REGRESPONSE", transport.responseDump);
            Log.d("EXECUTE", "In Register Execute");

            Object result = (Object)envelope.getResponse();
            //Log.d("Result", "Register result: " + result.toString());

            return result;          
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
```

The UserProfile class that is passed to the doInBackground method is simply a holder for a bunch of strings that contain the registration info. And as for the part the

```
Vector<PropertyInfo> properties = makeProperties(ServiceCall.REGISTER, profiles[0]);
```

call, this function simply calls a function called makeProperties that creates a PropertyInformation with a passed string and name, like so:

```
private PropertyInfo makeProperty(String name, String value)
{
    PropertyInfo newProperty = new PropertyInfo();
    newProperty.setName(name);
    newProperty.setValue(value);
    newProperty.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);

    return newProperty;
}
```

The name of the value that the web service expects is "registrationCode", and as I said, I've tried playing around with the value of the field. So an example of this call would be...

```
PropertyInfo regCode = makeProperty("registrationCode", "student123");
```

The web service is clearly getting SOMETHING that matches the registrationCode field, as it responds saying that the value it received is invalid. Unfortunately, at this stage of testing, this is the only web service call that requires paramaters that I can use, so I can't really test if any other service calls are having the same error. Does anybody have any tips?

Let me know if any more information, and any help will be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Here is a printout of the requestDump:

```
05-04 12:59:51.434: D/REGREQUEST(17492): <v:Envelope
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<v:Header /><v:Body>
<createStudentAccount xmlns="http://URL/" id="o0" c:root="1">
<fName i:type="d:string">Chandler</fName>
<lName i:type="d:string">Bing</lName>
<middleName i:type="d:string">M</middleName>
<userName i:type="d:string">lulz</userName>
<registrationCode i:type="d:string">student123</registrationCode>
<password i:type="d:string">pass</password>
<instructorName i:type="d:string">Instructor1</instructorName>
<schoolLocation i:type="d:string">Location1</schoolLocation>
</createStudentAccount></v:Body></v:Envelope>
```

I've never seen this "i:type="d:string"" stuff before, could that have anything to do with the problem?

Comment: I suggest you try to run the server call through a web proxy. That'll give you the opportunity to inspect the raw request and response. If you then compare a successful request from the iOS app with a failed attempt on Android, you should be able to deduce more information on what's going wrong where/when.

Comment: I've edited the post with a printout of the requestDump, and the only thing different between the iOS app's request and this one is the
    i:type="d:string"
and
    id="o0" c:root="1"
stuff.